# Decode Function in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone please help me to write a decode function in Informatica for the below case statement?

```
CASE WHEN Employee in ('210','220','230') and Score like '7%' THEN concat(SUBSTRING(Employee,1,2),'2')

WHEN Employee in ('210','220','230') and Score not like '7%' THEN concat(SUBSTRING(Employee,1,2),'1')

ELSE Employee END as New_Employee
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "a decode function" ?

Comment: Why do you think a DECODE function is capable of implementing this logic? Please update your question with what you’ve tried and the specific issue you are having

Comment: @Reynadan DECODE is a function available in Informatica

Answer (score 0):

You can use decode to test out multiple conditions like `CASE WHEN`. It works exacly like case when.

```
DECODE( TRUE,
        Employee in ('210','220','230') and substr(Score,1,1) = '7', concat(substr(Employee,1,2),'2') ,
        Employee in ('210','220','230') and substr(Score,1,1) <>'7',concat(substr(Employee,1,2),'1'), 
Employee )
```

So, it will check if first condition is true, if yes it will exit else check second, if true, it will exit and so on ...

Comment: does 'like' function work in informatica?

Comment: i am sorry, i was thinking SQL. i changed them to substr